# keytool -storepass option - Is this a password I create? Or a password provided to me with the certificate?

Tags: java, ssl, weblogic, keytool, obiee

I was told recently to use the following command to import a SSL certificate onto our weblogic server

```
keytool -import -file <ssl certificate filename> -alias alias name -keystore <keystorename> -storepass <password>
```

I was reading up on the options for this keytool command and am a bit confused by the -storepass option.

We currently do not use SSL on the server, and am switching over - So for the [-storepass] option is this a password that should be PROVIDED to me along WITH the certificate? Or is this going to be a password I am CREATING for the newly imported certificate?

Answer (score 1):

In order to add support to SSL to your weblogic server you need to import the SSL/TLS certificate to a keystore that will be used by the server. The attribute **-storepass** is related to the keystore passphrase, it was configured at the moment you generate the keystore.

The bellow command shows how to import a credentials into your keystore, pay attention in the fields you need to replace

```
keytool -v -importkeystore -srckeystore *yourkeystorePath* -srcstoretype *yourKeystoreType* -srcstorepass *yourKeystorePassword* -destkeystore *yourtargetKeystore* -deststoretype *yourTargetKeystoreType* -deststorepass *yourTargetKeyStorePass*
```